# writing comments that can't be deleted (VB & Java)

Tags: java, vb.net

Can one write important comments like the author name or company name at the top of a class *without* the ability to delete them? Either by backspace or mark all+delete. So when giving the code to someone, those comments can't be modified.

either in java : //Company Name: 
or vb : 'Company Name:

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Plain text files do not have DRM.

Comment: what would be the purpose of these comments?

Comment: @vandale I mentioned author/company name, so the name of who wrote that class.

Answer (score 2):

No. But you can use a version control software like SVN to check in your files with your comments. Then, if those comments are ever changed, you have historical documentation that the comments were there. And you can even see who changed the comments.

Answer (score 1):

No. The source code is just stored as text files. There's no way to restrict access to parts of a text file.